# How can I apply formatting to divIcon text in leaflet?

Tags: css, formatting, leaflet

Total javascript newbie here.

I'm using divIcon to display text on a map in leaflet.js, and can't work out how to apply formatting to the text as I would normally in html.

```
var myDate = L.divIcon({
            html: 'text'
        });
```

I need to change the text formatting (colour/size/bold), and to change the background colour and border size.

Thanks

Comment: If you look at the documentation, you can also insert a class there, so you can format the text using your own style, etc. [divicon-classname](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#divicon-classname) Besides, in place of `html` you not only put text but also html elements, e.g. `<div style="font-weight:bold">text</div>`